# bind failed: EADDRINUSE while starting Xbt tracker in Ubuntu

Tags: sockets, bittorrent

I follow these steps to install xbt on ubuntu.

1. Download Xbt from GitHub
2. install g++
3. install xbt
   4)create database and import data.

when I am going to start xbt ./xbt_tracker it shows bind failed: EADDRINUSE. Kindly help me I am stuck on this error for the last two days

kiran@kiran:/var/www/xbt_tracker$ ./xbt_tracker

bind failed: EADDRINUSE

Answer (score 0):

The error points to the port already being in use by another application or service. You can check which by using netstat:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

Comment: 15887/./xbt_tracker 

tcp6       0      0 :::2710                 :::*                    LISTEN      15887/./xbt_tracker

is this make an impact on my service

Comment: Looks like it's already running and you get the "bind failed" error when trying to start it for a second time